# Qt/webkit and flash

Tags: flash, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I have installed pyqt 4.8.1 on xp and Qt in package. I have a tag like

```
<object ...>
<param value='1.swf'>
<embed src='1.swf'></embed>
</param>
</object>
```

But Qt/webkit doesn't show flash. (there is not problem with code and IE or chrome).
Does Qt/webkit support flash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is enable plugins. See the python specific Qt example but in C++ its like this.

QWebPage *webpage = ...
webpage->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

Plugins are loaded by NPAPI
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI

Answer (score 0):

use AC_RunActiveContent.js. for your flash embed, it works in all browsers. This is included as the standard method of embedding within Dreamweaver, but is downloadable if you prefer to use another solution. you can download it here -->[link text](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/activecontent/articles/devletter.html)

Comment: thank u for your answer. but i think that problem is with flash plugin disabled (and not flash tag) and i try to enable plugin in pyqt/qtwebkit. and how to do this?