# Android WebView + Does it support embedded Flash files?

Tags: android, flash, webview, embed

Can a WebView in Android support embedded Flash files?

Using the default insert method of Dreamweaver, incorporating the swfobject_modified.js, I receive the standard "Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player."  If I attempt to add the file with a simple object/embed tag, I receive nothing.  What does WebView require to embed flash?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[Qt/webkit and flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348306/problem-with-qt-webkit-and-flash)